# disable gridview item onClick and enable on child gridview

Tags: android, gridview

[image]

like in this image

I am trying to do something like in this image but don't know where to start.

Comment: Follow this tutorial to get started with GridView : https://www.raywenderlich.com/127544/android-gridview-getting-started

Comment: Welcome ! Please take a [tour] and see [ask]. Stackoverflow is not use to ask for tutorial, you can find plenty using Search Engines.